# float:right moves other divs down

Tags: html, css

I have a div (`.contactquestion`) inside of another div (`.body`) that is trying to `float:right`, but when I put `float:right` onto `.contactquestion`, it moves the `.nav` class (the heading in the picture) down around 100px. I have absolutely no idea why. This is most of my HTML, but not all of my CSS. If you need more, I'd be happy to provide.

Does the float property usually do this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a Fiddle with everything. the central area will be a little messed up unless you stretch it, but that doesn't really matter at the moment. https://jsfiddle.net/BTJohnson/zo6132yL/

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

```css
.body{
      width: 60%;
      top: 100px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #444;
      color: white;
    }

    .businessinquiry {
      float: left;
      width: 45%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 25px;
    }

    .contactquestion {
      width: 45%;
      background-color: #444;
      padding: 5px;
      opacity: .9;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 25px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li class="home"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonHome.html"><img src="../pics/Logo.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
   <li class="about"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonAbout.html">About</a></li>
   <li class="mywork"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonMyWork.html">My Work</a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a class="active" href="BraxtonTJohnsonContact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="body">
  <div class="businessinquiry">
   <h2>Business Inquiries</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contactquestion">
   <div class="words">
    <h2>General Questions & Inquiries</h2>

   </div>
   <form method="post" action="../php/index.php">
        
       <input class="info" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
            
       <input class="info" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
            
       <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="How can I help?"></textarea>
            
       <input class="info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        
   </form>
  </div>
   <div class="social">

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide us a fiddle so that we can see the problem and help you in much better way.

Comment: Did you use clear:both?

Comment: I did. Put it right after .contactquestion div. Didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: You have to put clear both after divs who are using float property..give me 2 min checking your fiddle.

Comment: I'll play around with it too. Thanks man.

Comment: @BJohnson check this https://jsfiddle.net/zo6132yL/1/

Comment: Thank you! What exactly did you change?

Comment: As i said after float use clear:both and i did that. simple no extra css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add `.fixit` class to reset position of floating divs(`.businessinquiry`,`.contactquestion`) and remove `margin-top: 75px` off `.social`

```css
.fixit:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:.req-a-quote input[type="submit"]both;height:0;}
.fixit{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
* html .fixit{height:1%;}
.fixit{display:block;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("../pics/nature.png");
  background-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  opacity: .9;
}
 
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
 
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
}

/* Centre the page */

.body{
  width: 60%;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}

.businessinquiry {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.contactquestion {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 25px;
  
  float: right;
}

/* Centre the form within the page */
form {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style the text boxes */

input, textarea {
  height:30px;
  background:#444;
  border:1px solid white;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
  border:1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

#submit {
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  width: 9em;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 72px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color:#005f5f ;
}

.info[name="name"] {
  width: 8em;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.info[name='email'] {
  width: 8em;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 22px;
}

.message {
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.words {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #efefef;
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.social {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social img {
  margin: 75px;
  opacity: .9;
  size: 25px;

}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li class="home"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonHome.html"><img src="../pics/Logo.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>
   <li class="about"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonAbout.html">About</a></li>
   <li class="mywork"><a href="BraxtonTJohnsonMyWork.html">My Work</a></li>
   <li class="contact"><a class="active" href="BraxtonTJohnsonContact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="body">
  <!-- .row start -->
  <div class="row fixit">
  
  <div class="businessinquiry">
   <h2>Business Inquiries</h2>
   <p>Interested in working together? Fill out the simple form below with some more information about your project, and I'll be in touch.</p>
   <p>Don't be afraid to be honest with us about your timeline and your budget. We're upfront about our prices, and knowing beforehand how we can best help you will really help later on.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contactquestion">
   <div class="words">
    <h2>General Questions & Inquiries</h2>

   </div>
   <form method="post" action="../php/index.php">
        
       <input class="info" name="name" placeholder="What's your name?">
            
       <input class="info" name="email" type="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
            
       <textarea class="message" name="message" placeholder="How can I help?"></textarea>
            
       <input class="info" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        
   </form>
    
  </div>
     </div><!-- .row end -->
     
   <div class="social">
    <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/bjohnson.rbi"><img src="../pics/facebook.png"></a>
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/braxtontjohnson"><img src="../pics/twitter.png"></a>
    <a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/b_rax_johnson/"><img src="../pics/instagram.png"></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/RBIproductions"><img src="../pics/youtube.png"></a>
   </div>
      
 </div>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding 
`ul{margin:0}` to your css stylesheet? I think it has nothing to do with float.

And you have `top:100px` in .body class, you should also remove that.

Fiddle you provided doesnt really show any errors btw.

Comment: Removing the top:100px just moves it up to where the heading is sitting right now. and margin:0 doesn't do anything either. :/

Comment: Try removing margins on the floating boxes and do the spaces via width

Comment: Also no effect. This is quite the conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

I gone through the JSfidle. Actually for the class .social you have given margin-top: 75px.

.social {

```
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

And the divs with classes .businessinquiry . contactquestion, .social are inside the div with class .body. But you have give float left and right to .businessinquiry . contactquestion. There is no floating property for .social.

To solve the problem you need to do the following things.

- Place .social out side .body div to resolve it .
- use clear:both property to cancel the floating property after the
  .contactquestion div.
- social you have given margin-top: 75px. Remove this